# Object reference not set to an instance of an object a un contador

Tags: vb.net

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Calculadora1

{

public class Archivo
{
    String Ruta = "Archivo.txt";
    String[] contenido;       
    int numero2;
    public Archivo()
    {
    }

    public String Cargar(String xd)
    {          
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Ruta);
        int i, j;
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            contenido[i] = sr.ReadLine();
            i= i+1;
        }
        j = i;

        for(int x=0; x < i; x++)
        {
            if (contenido[x].Equals(xd))
            {
                numero2 = x + 1;
            }
            
        }

        sr.Close();
        return contenido[numero2];
    }

    public void Escribir(String Res, String Op)
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Ruta, true);
        sw.Write(Op);
        sw.Write("\n");
        sw.Write(Res);
        sw.Write("\n");
        sw.Close();
    }
    public String Mostrar1(String Res)
    {
        return Res;
    }

    public String Mostrar2(String Res)
    {
        return Res;
    }
}
}
```

Estoy haciendo un programa que lea un archivo y devuelva el valor para usarla en otra función pero cuando
lo ejecuto me aparece error en la parte de i++; comprendo que el error hace referencia a que un valor es nulo, pero no entiendo a que valor se refiere ya que i lo estoy usando como contador y el sr.readline es para leer el archivo en si, asi que no se como repararlo, he intentado de todo para poner valores y tratar de deshacerme del error sin exito

Comment: la variable contenido la  defines como  un  arreglo de  String pero nunca la inicializas, en otras palabras, nunca  creas  el arreglo. Por lo tanto, si referencias a contenido[1] te da error porque no existe el elemento 1. Para  inicializar contenido deberia hacer algo como contenido=new String[1000] para crear 1000 elementos. En tu caso debes primero saber cuantos registros son para crear el string o simplemente utiliza una lista List<String> contenido y le añades a esta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes inicializar la variable **String[] contenido;** es una variable nula.

valla **contenido = null** y al realizar contenido[0] quieres a **null** extraerle la posición **0**, te va dar un error, y así con cualquier posición del arreglo.

Solo inicializa la variable **contenido**

1. Primer Método Inicializar la variable contenido en el constructor.

```
using ...;

namespace Calculadora1

{

public class Archivo
{
    String Ruta = "Archivo.txt";
    String[] contenido;       
    int numero2;
    public Archivo()
    {
      // INICIALIZAR LA VARIABLE contenido, Estoy dando la manera más "eficiente" de obtener el número de líneas suponiendo que el archivo es grande.
      StreamReader srStreamReader = new StreamReader(Ruta);
      int i = 0;
      while (srStreamReader.ReadLine() != null) { i++; }
      srStreamReader.Close();
      contenido = new String[i];
    }

    public String Cargar(String xd)
    {          
        ...
    }

    public void Escribir(String Res, String Op)
    {
        ...
    }
    public String Mostrar1(String Res)
    {
        ...
    }

    public String Mostrar2(String Res)
    {
        ...
    }
}
}
```

2. Segundo Método Cambio de Tipo de Dato a Lista

```
using ...;

namespace Calculadora1

{

public class Archivo
{
    String Ruta = "Archivo.txt";
    // String[] contenido; // cambiamos el Tipo de Dato a Lista.
    List<String> contenido;
    int numero2;
    public Archivo()
    {
      // INICIALIZAR LA VARIABLE contenido
      contenido = new List<String>();
    }

    public String Cargar(String xd)
    {          
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Ruta);
      int i, j;
      i = 0;
      j = 0;
      while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
      {
        contenido.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        i= i+1;
      }
      j = i;

      // lo siguiente se puede mejorar gracias a la lista pero para seguir tu lógica voy a recorrerlo con for.
      for(int x=0; x < i; x++)
      {
        if (contenido[x].Equals(xd))
        {
            numero2 = x + 1;
        }  
      }

      sr.Close();
      return contenido[numero2];
    }

    public void Escribir(String Res, String Op)
    {
        ...
    }
    public String Mostrar1(String Res)
    {
        ...
    }

    public String Mostrar2(String Res)
    {
        ...
    }
}
}
```

Tengo una observación en la lógica de tú código puede mejorarse, las siguientes son solo sugerencias, siempre hay distintas formas de optimizar código.

1. Usa Lista para almacenar el contenido.
2. En el constructor, Lee el archivo y almacena el resultado en la variable **contenido** ( .Add() )
3. El tú método carga, solo haz un .Contains() a la variable **contenido** sí devuelve true entonces retornas el valor.

PD:
Te va salir otro problema cuando la variable **numero2** no tenga valor (es por que estas buscando alguna "algo" que no esta contenida en la variable **contenido**) en el caso de que no coincidencia yo sugeriría que devuelvas un nulo.

Comment: Por favor leer [answer]. Tu respuesta parece más un comentario. Cuando tengas la [reputación suficiente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) podrás comentar en cualquier publicación. Te sugiero eliminar esta respuesta o hacer clic en [edit] para argumentarla y mostrar al OP la forma de resolver el problema, incluyendo el código relevante. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Okey, trataré de explicarlo mejor.

Comment: Ya, muy buena explicación. Todavía me falta por aprender, has sido de gran ayuda. Y tomaré tus consejos sobre el programa para optimizarlo de una mejor manera, muchas gracias!